# odd and even page left and right margin mismatch in svjour3

Tags: margins

This is all the prelude I use for svjour3. Is there something wrong?

```
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
\documentclass{svjour3}   % onecolumn (standard format)
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof

\usepackage{graphicx}
\journalname{International Journal}

\usepackage{natbib}  % for citation
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{booktabs} % used for tables
\usepackage{multirow} % used for tables to merge multiple rows
\usepackage{bigdelim} % used for tables to set spacing
\usepackage{bigstrut} % used for tables to set spacing
\usepackage{dirtytalk}

\usepackage{geometry,caption}
\usepackage{rotating} % for sidewaystable
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for sideway figure
\usepackage{tabulary} 
\usepackage{siunitx} %sidewaystable
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
```

[image]

Comment: This is normal for a two-sided document. Try if option `oneside` for the documentclass is available.

Answer (score 2):

Don't load the geometry package (or load it with the option `pass`). It overwrites the layout.

With geometry:

[image]

Without geometry:

[image]

Comment: I tried it without geometry. The right margin increased dramatically like the one above.

Comment: Well it is the layout of the class. If you don't want it you naturally can change it with geometry, but then it is your responsabily to get the correct margin.